# Setupping memcache as default only for doctrine queries in symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, memcached

I am trying to setup memcache for my doctrine queries by default in my prod environment, not going really well can't really find how to do that in the doc..

Is there a simple setting to do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of cache you might want to use: **query cache** and **results cache**. You can read more about it in the [doctrine docs](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/caching.html#query-cache-result-cache).

In the examples you'll find `Doctrine_Cache_Apc` driver. Using other kinds of drivers, like memcache, is dead simple. Just use appropriate class name (for memcache it's `Doctrine_Cache_Memcache`).

Example (in `ProjectConfiguration.class.php`):

```
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
{
    $cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Memcache( $options ); // insert your options!
    $manager->setAttribute( Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, $cacheDriver );
}
```

My article about cache in symfony+doctrine might be helpful as well: http://www.zalas.eu/symfony-meets-apc-alternative-php-cache

I mention APC but it'll work for memcache too.